# Removing characters at end of cell in excel and output as number

Tags: excel

I have a large dataset that has multiple date columns, but for various reasons the dates will sometimes have " A" or "*" at the end, so my date column has some string entries such as "01-Oct-2015 A"

Is there any way when removing characters to automatically read the new value as a number?

I tried making a new column to remove the asterisks and " A" and maintain the original entries that were read as numbers with the formula
`=IFS(RIGHT(K2,2)=" A",LEFT(K2,LEN(K2)-2),RIGHT(K2,1)="*",LEFT(K2,LEN(K2)-1),ISNUMBER(K2),K2)`
However, the cells that have been modified are still being interpreted as strings and not numbers. I changed the number formats in this new column to long date, and it is working for the ones that did not need altered.

Comment: Maybe wrap your formula in `DATEVALUE()`?

Comment: Post few examples of what you have and what you expect. Using **[Markdown_Table_Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)**

Comment: Or you could try this formula : `=-LOOKUP(0,-LEFT(K2,ROW($1:$10)-1))` or, `=-LOOKUP(0,-LEFT(K2,ROW($1:$10)-1))` it will return a number which you need to format as dates

Comment: Even your formula works, I have tested now, as mentioned above by @cybernetic.nomad sir, you need to wrap inside a `DATEVALUE( )` or add a `0` at the end `=IFS(RIGHT(K2,2)=" A",LEFT(K2,LEN(K2)-2),RIGHT(K2,1)="*",LEFT(K2,LEN(K2)-1),ISNUMBER(K2),K2)+0` this will return a number which you need to format as Excel Date. If you are `MS365` user then : `=TEXTBEFORE(K2," ")+0`

Comment: Sorry the second formula with `LOOKUP()` would be : `=-LOOKUP(0,-LEFT(K2,SEQUENCE(10,,0)))`